# Share a Spotify song url in a exact second

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

I want to share a song url with exact second but i dont have idea what is the url parameters(
at the end of the url) or if this is not possible or you need to run javascript or use Chrome DevTools for it. If anyone have idea how to do this. I need this for html iframe.
This is a two example song url:

https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/3lq06iX09nUI5DH2014BWi?
https://open.spotify.com/track/3lq06iX09nUI5DH2014BWi?

Two same songs but one its embed for iframe and other no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Lost-feature-URI-link-with-timestamp/td-p/5212621), the feature to share a song link with an exact timestamp has been removed as of May 2021.